# Cloud Code Kubernetes spawn python enoent error in VS Code when attaching a debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-kubernetes-engine, vscode-debugger, enoent, google-cloud-code

I come across a very weird case in my Visual Studio Code when trying to debug a simple Kubernetes app using **CloudCode extension**. If anyone has worked with cloudcode in VS Code, any suggestions on this issue would be very appreciated.

I'm trying out a simple single endpoint Flask application and I can successfully build and deploy my container in Google Kubernetes. The endpoint is working fine too. However, when I try to attach the debugger to my pod, it always fails with the following error message: spawn python ENOENT Source: Cloud Code (Extension)

[image]

Here are my launch and attach snippets in launch.json file

```
{
    "name": "Attach to Kubernetes Pod (Python)",
    "type": "cloudcode.kubernetes",
    "request": "attach",
    "language": "Python",
    "debugPort": 3000,
    "podSelector": {
        "app": "flask-test-kustomize-app"
    },
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/flask_app_internal/app",
    "remoteRoot": "/app"
},
{
    "name": "Run on Kubernetes",
    "type": "cloudcode.kubernetes",
    "request": "launch",
    "skaffoldConfig": "${workspaceFolder}/skaffold.yaml",
    "watch": true,
    "cleanUp": false,
    "portForward": true,
    "imageRegistry": "eu.gcr.io/xxx-XXXXXX",
}
```

And this is my simple Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc libc-dev \
    linux-headers build-base libc6-compat \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r /tmp/requirements.txt \
    && apk del .build-deps gcc libc-dev build-base linux-headers 
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app/
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app
EXPOSE 80 8010
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"]
```

where my Flask main.py is a very simple Flask app with one endpoint. The app contains debugpy

```
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask
import time
import debugpy
debugpy.listen(('0.0.0.0', 3000))

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/messages/', methods=['GET'])
def get_messages():
    v = 'hello'
    return v

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = os.getenv("HOST", "0.0.0.0")
    port = os.getenv("PORT", "8010")
    app.run(debug=False, port=port, host=host)
```

I used debugpy instead of ptvsd (ptvsd is used in google cloudcode vscode docs examples) but this debugger is outdated now.

My Skaffold file looks like this

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta19
kind: Config
build:
  tagPolicy:
    sha256: {}
  artifacts:
  - context: flask_app_internal
    image: flask_test/el-flask-kustomize-test
    docker:
      dockerfile: flask.dockerfile
deploy:
  kustomize:
      paths: ["base"]
profiles:
- name: cloudbuild
  build:
    googleCloudBuild: {}
```

I tried the same app with the same dockerfile on my local server and debugger worked fine. However, I always have this spawn python enoent issue when trying this with cloudcode.kubernetes in VS Code.

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for the feedback. Sorry that both configs(launch/attach) didn't work out for you, it appears that you are running in to this error likely because of Python is not in the path of VSCode. Can you validate you can access the Python from the VSCode terminal. i created a Github issue to track on our repo(Cloud Code VSCode extension) for further investigation, please use the github task for further followup to resolve the issue. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode/issues/494

Comment: @SivaKalva Thanks Siva for reply. Yes I can access the Python from the VSCode terminal with no problem. I also attached python.pythonPath and PYTHONPATH to my terminal.integrated.env.linux in settings.json file. And debugging some other remote Flask apps works smooth with python.